# Why does Henle Verlag recommend different fingerings for the same bar?

Tags: piano, fingering

Image attached, from Schubert Impromptu op90 no2. Relevant fingerings are in red boxes. I don't understand why the fingering has changed when the bar is the same and the notes before and after are essentially the same (I assume?).

[image]

Comment: The notes before are not the same - it's a two note chord in the first case and a 4-note chord in the second. But I don't see how that is relevant, really. The 5 on the F# in the second case doesn't look right to me. But the fingering was just made up by the editor of the edition, so treat it with as much respect as it deserves!

Answer (score 1):

They are different due to the different chords approaching these identical bars. Fingerings are suggestions made by the editors who tried to help ensure that the chords progresses smoothly.

Much as ornaments, e.g a trill; you need to identify the approaching and subsequent note before deciding the which notes you need to start and end with.

Comment: I know the chords are different but I don't see why that should justify changing the fingering. It is still easier to use ones 3rd finger, it seems to me.

Comment: In that case, you are totally free to go for your own fingerings, whichever puts you at ease when playing is the best choice. Different hands and fingerings call for different fingering alternatives. Enjoy your Schubert!